# Hi I am using dispatch CLI work to gather with LUIS & QNA but when i am hitting endpoint i am getting 401 please retrain & republish

Tags: azure, dispatch, azure-bot-service, azure-language-understanding

```
    `Hi this my code i am working on LUIS and QNA Services together but when i am sending message on Emulator i am getting some error msg
    1)The bot encountered an error or bug.
    2)To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code. `
```

const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({[image]
applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`
}, {
includeAllIntents: false,
includeInstanceData: false
}, true);

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
    console.log('Processing Message Activity.');
    let con:any=context;
    console.log(context);
    // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
    const recognizerResult = await dispatchRecognizer.recognize(con);
    console.log("recogResult- ",recognizerResult);
    // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
    const intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(recognizerResult);
    console.log("Intent -",intent);
    // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
    await this.dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult);

    await next();
});
```

Comment: i am referring this doc please check this link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?tabs=js&view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

The open-source Bot Framework SDK provides over 40 common reusable building blocks and samples available in .net, JavaScript (es5, es6), Python and Java. These samples build from a simple echo to samples for dialog, state management and authentication. These can be combined to create more complex solutions which are also used in the Virtual Assistant solution.

Below is a partial list of samples. Check out the whole list https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples

**[NLP-with-dispatch](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch)**: demonstrates how to dispatch across LUIS and QnA Maker.